# Embedding of a topological manifold

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology

We know the celebrated 'Whitney embedding theorem' for smooth manifold that says any n-dimensional manifold can be smoothly embedded in $\ \mathbb R^{2n} \ $. Now my question is:  Is there similar version for topological manifolds? that is for which least N(n) any n-dim topological manifold will have a locally flat embedding  in $\ \mathbb R^{N(n)} \ $. It's clear that for smoothable topological manifolds N will be equal to 2n for 
$\ \mathbb RP^{2n} \ $ can not be embedded(locally flat) in $\ \mathbb R^{2n-1} \ $ ie. $\ \mathbb RP^{2n} \ $ can not be realized as topological submanifold of $\ \mathbb R^{2n-1} \ $ where n is a power of 2.

But for nonsmoothable topological manifolds can this N be made less?

Comment: If anything $N$ would have to be larger, because every smooth manifold is a topological manifold.

Comment: My questin is particularly for nonsmoothable manifolds. @Joe Johnson 126

Comment: This might be of interest: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34658/is-there-a-whitney-embedding-theorem-for-non-smooth-manifolds